# How to generate 2-digits distant PIN codes?

Tags: java

I want to generate 4-digits PIN codes that are at least 2-digits distant from each other.

For example:

- 5235 and 4068 is OK
- 5235 and 5339 is OK
- 5235 and 2553 is OK
- 5235 and 5236 is NOT OK
- 5325 and 5235 is NOT OK (permutation)

Permutation is easy to check but how to check the distance?

Comment: Count how often each digit is used.

Comment: How do you define *digit distance*?

Comment: @JanezKuhar the number of differences. Mostly to avoid typing an existing PIN by accident with only 1 mistake (1-digit distance).

Comment: So you want a minimum [digit distance](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/digit-distance-of-two-numbers-javascript) of 2 but with the added condition that if two pins are permutations of one another, they aren't a valid pair.

Comment: @didil Is it some kind of an OTP that you're trying to generate? If it is meant to be secure, then you should using a SecureRandom generator - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html

Comment: What abut 5195 and 5590 ? Is it ok or not ok?

Comment: Is this a class assignment? Because in the real world, typing an existing PIN would not be a problem.

Comment: @JanezKuhar this is exacly what I'm looking for :)

Comment: @SiddharthKamaria I already use SecureRandom to generate the PIN

Comment: @user3437460 there is more than 1 difference so this should by ok

Comment: @NomadMaker this is assignment

Comment: The rules here state that we have to see the code you've tried first for homework assignments. Yet, you neither provided code, nor were you up front about the assignment. We are not a homework-writing service.

Comment: @NomadMaker ok this has nothing to do with homework. I want to "assign" a PIN code to a person. My bad

Comment: How much research did you do on the actual assignment of PIN's to people before asking this question?

Comment: This error correction technique is called [**hamming distance**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance).

Comment: Why not just subtract two PINs and verify that the difference is OK?

Comment: @didil Your 2nd test case `5235 and 5339 is OK` should be NOT OK right?

Comment: @Joop Eggen It sounds familiar but I had completely forgotten about it. Thanks :)

Comment: @user3437460 there is more than 1 difference so this is ok.

Answer (score 1):

If have have no issues with permutation with your given problem description, it seems you only want to check if the digit of each position is having a difference of at least 2.

There are so many ways to do it in Java. One "primitive" way I personally like is using basic math operations:

```
public boolean isDistantPins (int pinA, int pinB, int requiredSpacedDigits, int distance){
    int spacedDigits = 0, aDigit = 0, bDigit = 0;
    while(pinA > 0 ){
        aDigit = pinA % 10;    //get last digit from the right
        bDigit = pinB % 10;    //get last digit from the right

        if(Math.abs(aDigit - bDigit) >= distance)    //find difference
            spacedDigits ++;

        pinA = pinA / 10;      //remove last digit from the right
        pinB = pinB / 10;      //remove last digit from the right
    }
    return spacedDigits == requiredSpacedDigits;
}
```

**To invoke it:**

```
System.out.println(isDistantPins(5235, 4068, 1, 2));
System.out.println(isDistantPins(5235, 5339, 1, 2));
System.out.println(isDistantPins(5235, 2553, 1, 2));
System.out.println(isDistantPins(5235, 5236, 1, 2));
System.out.println(isDistantPins(5235, 5235, 1, 2));
```

**Output:**

```
true
true
true
false
false
```

Note that this does not check the permutation. Hence you can run this after your permutation check (which you have no issues) so the codes for checking permutation is not shown here.

Comment: This does not answer the question though. This calculates the sum of how far apart each digit of pin1 is relative to the digit of pin2 in the same position, whereas the question is about how many digits are the same in the same position in both pin numbers

Answer (score 1):

The logic is the following:

- Check if pin1 is permutation
- Check every digit of pin1 against the digit in the same position of pin2 using `/`, `%`.
- Count the amount of same digits.
- Return true/false based on the number of them.

Assuming you have a way to check for permutations, here's a complete solution:

```java
class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /*
         * 5235 and 4068 is OK
         * 5235 and 5339 is OK
         * 5235 and 2553 is OK
         * 5235 and 5236 is NOT OK
         * 5325 and 5235 is NOT OK (permutation)
         */

        // threshold is the maximum number of digits that can be the same
        // while the pin1, pin2 are distant enough; in this case 2
        int threshold = 2;
        int pinLength = 4;

        System.out.println(areDistant(5235, 4068, threshold, pinLength));
        System.out.println(areDistant(5235, 5339, threshold, pinLength));
        System.out.println(areDistant(5235, 2553, threshold, pinLength));
        System.out.println(areDistant(5235, 5236, threshold, pinLength));
        System.out.println(areDistant(5325, 5235, threshold, pinLength));
    }

    public static boolean areDistant(int pin1, int pin2, int threshold, int pinLength) {
        if (isPermutation(pin1, pin2))
            return false;

        int sameDigits = 0;
        int ithDigit1, ithDigit2;
        for (int i=0; i<pinLength; i++) {
            ithDigit1 = (int) (pin1 / Math.pow(10, i)) % 10;
            ithDigit2 = (int) (pin2 / Math.pow(10, i)) % 10;
            // System.out.println(ithDigit1);
            // System.out.println(ithDigit2);
            if ( ithDigit1 == ithDigit2)
                sameDigits += 1;
        }
        return sameDigits <= threshold;
    }

    private static  boolean isPermutation(int pin1, int pin2) {
        return false;
        // fill the code here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the XOR of two numbers.
Count the number of set bits.